# How to invert a chart in Highcharts through code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to invert a chart through code in Highcharts.

I am setting the chart inverted property:

```
chart.inverted = true;
chart.redraw();
```

You can see the code I am using here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wajood/Hz4bH/

This doesn't invert the chart. It seems to me that the redraw() function doesn't seem to care for the inverted property.

Any help/suggestions/tips in the matter will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: jfi if you resize window after invert, i will redraw chart

Comment: @eicto odd - that does appear to work, although it is extremely buggy in FF18 here. The data is completely misaligned when resizing the window a second time.

Comment: I tried setting the chart.setSize(chart.width,chart.height), but then the chart goes all empty...(the series disappears)

Comment: so eicto, each time i resize the chart, you will redraw the chart? ;)

Comment: What's an inverted chart ? There's no property with this name. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `redraw()` will only redraw data changes. Browsing the methods in the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart) there does not appear to be a method which will change the `inverted` setting of an existing chart.

Your only option in this case is to destroy the existing chart and create a new one with the relevant `chart.inverted` setting.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem and was able to solve it using `chart.update`.

```
chart.update({chart: {inverted: true}});
chart.redraw();
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update